# Mesclar POJO e Entity

Tags: java

Estou estudando JPA e preciso serializar uma entidade:

```
    @Entity
    public class Employee {

         @Id
         private Integer id;       
         ...
    }
```

É boa prática serializar uma  entidade diretamente assim como faço com um POJO? Ou tem abordagens melhores?

Imaginei uma abordagem onde serializo no formato json uma classe abstrata  que é implementada pela entidade, seria uma boa abordagem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tem abordagens melhores sim.

Primeiro que as entidades tem como responsabilidade fazer o mapeamento das suas tabelas no banco de dados. Fazer com que elas também assumam a parte de representar as informações em formato JSON me parece ferir o **SRP** (*Single Responsability Principle*).

Se você precisar de alguma flexibilidade nas informações a serem exibidas neste Json (colocar mais uma informação ou esconder uma outra), você terá que controlar isto dentro da entity, deixando ela muito mais complexa e confusa, provavelmente cheia de annotations do JPA e da biblioteca Json.

O ideal é não serializar suas entidades, a menos que eles trafeguem por algum tipo de interface remota (usando EJB remoto, por exemplo). Como isto é um caso raro, não se preocupe com isto.

A solução é deixar as entidades com a responsabilidade delas: mapear as tabelas e trazer informações das mesmas. Se quer apresentar as informações delas em um Json, crie algum tipo de Dto (mesmo que seja idêntica a entidade):

```
class EmployeeDto implements Serializable {
    private Integer id;
}
```

E use alguma ferramenta de mapper (como o ModelMapper) para transferir as informações da entidade para o Dto.

```
EmployeeDto dto = modelMapper.map(employeeEntity, EmployeeDto.class);
```

Isto deixará as responsabilidades separadas e te dará poder para alterar o retorno do Json alterando apenas o Dto, sem se preocupar com os impactos na (ou da) entity dentro da sua aplicação.